# Didn't installing types when NODE_ENV=production

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have types in my devDependencies, and this test stage in gitlab pipeline:

- npm install --production=false
- npm i jest
- npm run test

When pipeline start: npm run test
He throw me many errors about he can't find types.
Error examples:

1. Could not find a declaration file for module 'bcrypt'. '/builds/onix-systems/breakout-network-backend/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/bcrypt` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'bcrypt';`
2. Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'.
3. Could not find a declaration file for module 'hbs'. '/builds/onix-systems/breakout-network-backend/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/hbs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'hbs';`
   5 import { handlebars } from 'hbs';

And he's throwing them only when NODE_ENV=production
If NODE_ENV something else he works normally

I tried do this stage in my local machine and it's too works normaly.
In my local machine npm install --production=false works good and installing all Dependencies with devDependencies.

I tried to changed npm install to npm install --only=prod && npm install --only=dev and tried npm ci --include=dev, that didn't work.

This what i have in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
 "build": "nest build",
 "start": "nest start",
 "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
 "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
 "start:prod": "pm2 start --no-daemon",
 "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
 "test": "jest",
 "test:e2e": "dotenv -e .env.test npm run db:reset:force && dotenv -e .env.test npm run test:config:e2e",
 "start:docs": "npx @compodoc/compodoc -p tsconfig.json",
 "test:watch": "jest --watch",
 "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
 "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
 "test:config:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
 "db:reset": "prisma migrate reset",
 "db:migrate:dev": "prisma migrate dev",
 "db:migrate:prod": "npx prisma migrate deploy",
 "db:reset:force": "prisma migrate reset --force",
 "db:generate": "prisma generate",
 "db:format": "prisma format",
 "prepare": "husky install"
},
 "dependencies": {
    "@adminjs/design-system": "3.1.8",
    "@adminjs/express": "5.1.0",
    "@adminjs/nestjs": "5.1.0",
    "@adminjs/prisma": "3.0.1",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "3.245.0",
    "@casl/ability": "6.3.3",
    "@casl/prisma": "1.3.3",
    "@fast-csv/format": "4.3.5",
    "@liaoliaots/nestjs-redis": "9.0.5",
    "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "1.8.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/config": "2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/event-emitter": "1.3.1",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/passport": "9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "9.1.6",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "6.1.4",
    "@nestjs/terminus": "9.1.4",
    "@nestjs/testing": "9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/throttler": "^4.0.0",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "9.1.6",
    "@nodeteam/nestjs-pipes": "1.2.1",
    "@ntegral/nestjs-sentry": "4.0.0",
    "@prisma/client": "4.8.1",
    "@socket.io/redis-adapter": "8.1.0",
    "@supercharge/request-ip": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.0",
    "adminjs": "6.8.4",
    "bcrypt": "5.1.0",
    "class-transformer": "0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "0.13.2",
    "convert-excel-to-json": "1.7.0",
    "csv-parser": "3.0.0",
    "dayjs": "1.11.7",
    "dotenv-cli": "^7.1.0",
    "express": "4.18.2",
    "express-basic-auth": "1.2.1",
    "hbs": "4.2.0",
    "helmet": "6.0.1",
    "ioredis": "5.2.5",
    "jest": "29.5.0",
    "module-alias": "2.2.2",
    "nodemailer": "6.9.0",
    "p-queue": "6.6.2",
    "p-retry": "4.2.0",
    "passport-jwt": "4.0.1",
    "prisma": "4.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "7.8.0",
    "socket.io": "4.6.1",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.0",
    "twilio": "3.84.1"
   }
  "devDependencies": {
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@nestjs/cli": "9.1.8",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "9.0.4",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/convert-excel-to-json": "^1.7.1",
    "@types/express": "4.17.15",
    "@types/hbs": "4.0.1",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/nodemailer": "6.4.7",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "3.0.8",
    "@types/supertest": "2.0.12",
    "@types/xlsx": "^0.0.36",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.1",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "git-commit-msg-linter": "^4.5.1",
    "husky": "8.0.3",
    "pm2": "5.2.2",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.21",
    "supertest": "6.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "9.4.2",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@modules(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/modules$1",
      "^@decorators(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/decorators$1",
      "^@interceptors(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/interceptors$1",
      "^@providers(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/providers$1",
      "^@constants(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/constants$1",
      "^@pipes(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/pipes$1",
      "^@helpers(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/helpers$1",
      "^@guards(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/guards$1",
      "^@config(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/config$1",
      "^src(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src$1",
      "^@enums(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/enums$1",
      "^@filters(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/filters$1",
      "^@tests(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/tests$1"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Is there any reason you have NODE_ENV set to production when running tests? Setting that variable to production, will instruct npm to only install production dependencies, and that causes your test script to fail because it cannot find the type packages. Those errors are expected. A solution to your problem is to not have this varible set when running the test script.

Comment: Could you maybe include your package.json? Seeing how you have your scripts and dependencies configured would make it easier to tell what's going on.

Besides that, just setting NODE_ENV to "test" might be an easy fix.

Comment: @Phantom, I added package.json to my description.

Comment: Hmm... I don't have that much experience with this, so I must admit that I don't immediately see what the problem is. I'm curious about one thing though; when you say `npm ci --include=dev` "doesn't work", what do you mean by that exactly? Can you tell whether the dev dependencies actually don't get installed, or whether maybe ts-jest just can't find them?

Also, I have to ask - since you said that setting NODE_ENV to a different value fixes the problem, is it really necessary to have it set to production? If so, why?

Comment: @Phantom npm ci --include=dev must installing all dependencies with devDependencies, but it didn't install them, i have same error with types. I have test stage in pipeline and i need to know that my code 100% tested, whatever it's NODE_ENV=production or NODE_ENV=dev. I have one opinion how i can fix it but idk it's real to do or no, can i change NODE_ENV for example on 'test' only for this stage?